# Merging reshaped data frames and replicating values based on categories

Tags: r

I have the two following data frames, the first representing frequencies and the second representing individual events. I am attempting to add a column to the second data which merges the data from the first to the second, conditional on the row/column.

```
  event a b c
      w 0 1 3
      x 3 4 0
      y 6 0 4
      z 0 0 4

      event person
      w      b
      w      b
      x      a
      x      b
      x      b
      z      c
      z      a
      y      b
      y      c
      y      a
      y      c

counts <- data.frame (event= c("w", "x", "y", "z"), a= c(0, 3, 6, 0), b=c(1, 4, 0, 0), c=c(3, 0, 4, 4))
cases <- data.frame(event=c("w", "w", "x", "x", "x", "z", "z", "y", "y", "y", "y"), 
                        person=c("b", "b", "a", "b", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "c"))
```

Goal:

```
  case person freq
  w      b      1
  w      b      1
  x      a      3
  x      b      4
  x      b      4
  z      c      0
  z      a      0
  y      b      0
  y      c      4
  y      a      6
  y      c      4
```

Without much success. I was able to use the `reshape` package to generate the first DF of frequencies, but cant figure out how to combine them.

Comment: @Codoremifa: I didn't see a strategy for using `merge` in this instance. Care to post what you were thinking?

Comment: I hope I understood the question correctly - `library(reshape2);
    countsmelted <- melt(counts, id.vars = "event");
    colnames(countsmelted) <- c("event","person","freq");
    merge(cases, countsmelted, all.x = TRUE, by = c("event","person"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "[" function can take a two column matrix as an argument into a matrix object. It's a partial inverse of `table`. There's also an `as.data.frame.table` function.

```
mcounts <- data.matrix(counts[-1])
mcounts[ cbind(cases$event, cases$person)]
 [1] 1 1 3 4 4 4 0 0 4 6 4
cases$freq <- mcounts[ cbind(cases$event, cases$person)]
 cases
#------------
   event person freq
1      w      b    1
2      w      b    1
3      x      a    3
4      x      b    4
5      x      b    4
6      z      c    4
7      z      a    0
8      y      b    0
9      y      c    4
10     y      a    6
11     y      c    4
```

This is not an exact solution because I didn't take the time to lable the rows of the table correctly:

```
> tcounts <- data.matrix(tcounts)
> class(tcounts) <- 'table'
> tcounts
     a b c
[1,] 0 1 3
[2,] 3 4 0
[3,] 6 0 4
[4,] 0 0 4
> as.data.frame(tcounts)
   Var1 Var2 Freq
1     A    a    0
2     B    a    3
3     C    a    6
4     D    a    0
5     A    b    1
6     B    b    4
7     C    b    0
8     D    b    0
9     A    c    3
10    B    c    0
11    C    c    4
12    D    c    4
```